# Transactional support in WebSphere MQ classes for Java

Tags: java, transactions, ibm-mq

I  want to apply transactional support in my Java class, which receives messages from the queue in WebSphere MQ.  I use WebSphere MQ classes for Java. And i find article: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266535 There is written, that transactional support for classes for Java is not available. This means that I must recoding my class with classes for JMS?? And this means, that any application, which requires transactional support, I need to program, using only classes for JMS?

Comment: Are you interested in using 2 phase distributed transactions? Or are you interested in a single phase local transactions - what MQ would call a syncpoint?

But for distributed 2 phase transactions you need to use the JMS code via a supported JavaEE application server.

Local single phase transactions could be JMS or via the classes for Java.

Comment: Matt, move your comment to an answer and provide links to the appropriate docs such as http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031490_.htm?lang=en or else I will do so and poach your points. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in using 2-phase distributed transactions? Or are you interested in a single phase local transactions - what MQ would call a syncpoint?

For distributed 2 phase transactions you need to use the [JMS code](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031160_.htm) via a supported JavaEE application server.

Local single phase transactions could be JMS or via the classes for Java.